# schtasks asking for password at task creation

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have to schedule the launch of a program and I have to do that through Task Scheduler. 
I want to set the task to *Run whether user is logged on or not* and I don't want to check the 
 *Do not store password* box, but then Task Scheduler asks me for username and password when finishing the creation of the task. Actually the username is correct but the password (the PIN I use to access my computer at every boot) isn't correct, Task Scheduler gives this error: 
"*...cannot apply your changes. The user account is unknown, the password is incorrect, or the account does not have permission to modify the task.*". 
I don't want to check the *Run only when user is logged on* option because the program will show up every time, actually is running silent having that other option checked, but to avoid the password request I am forced to check the *Do not store password* box but, by doing this, since it doesn't store password, it can access only the local archive, is what that box caption says. 
I really need to solve that password related problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because the windows pin and password are two different things. Your account still has a separate password even if you typically login with a "Windows Hello" pin or biometrics. You will need to figure out what your password is and use that. If you login in with a Microsoft account this is the same password you use to login in to Microsoft websites.

Comment: Thanks @pholly, it worked! I used my microsoft.com password.